# WhenActivated called after App.OnSleep and not called after App.Resume

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I'm developing a Xamarin Forms app with ReactiveUI and I've noticed some strange behavior on Android.

The first page has a View and ViewModel and both implement the `WhenActivated`.

If I start the app and I press the home button to send the app to the background before the (XamarinForms) first page gets shown then I have this order of function calls. (this is easier to reproduce if you start the app from VS in debug mode while the phone screen is locked).

1. `App.OnStart` - OK
2. `App.OnSleep` - OK
3. `FirstPageViewModel.WhenActivated` - strange. Why after `OnSleep`?
4. `FirstPageView.WhenActivated` - strange. Why after `OnSleep`?

If I resume the App ( the First Page is visible)

5. `App.Resume` - OK
6. No call to `WhenActivated`  - strange, but somehow expected because of point 3 and 4

If I send the app to the background and resume it again everything is as expected.

7. `App.OnSleep` - OK
8. `App.Resume` - OK
9. `FirstPageViewModel.WhenActivated` - OK
10. `FirstPageView.WhenActivated` - OK

Is this by design?

Comment: I highlighted your code samples and improved the list formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to say that there aren't inherit issues in [View Activation](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/1116), but I think this may be correct.

If you are starting your app the app start sequence would fire.  Then the app would realize it's slept right after the startup sequence.  After the app comes back from sleep it activates the views because it had to immediately sleep (which I am not sure is a real world scenario, how do you start an app when the screen is locked?)

When resuming an application in XF as long as the OS hasn't garbage collected, the view is already activated.  So I would expect the view to reactivate.  View Activation isn't about when the screen visibility, more than the step after instantiating the ViewModel or View.  So it is generally responding to "ViewAppearing" and "View Disappearing" events.

In addition, iOS an Android handle "View Activation" differently.  It might be worth reading [Android Activity Lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/activity-lifecycle/). You'll notice that the activity stays active after it's been presented until dismissed by the user or collected by the OS.

I think this is less about how ReactiveUI is handling view activation and more about how XF abstracts view activation over the various platforms it supports.

All that to say, yes this is by design.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. The real world scenario: The user taps the app icon, a blank page appears and it takes 2 - 4 seconds for Xamarin Forms to load the first View. In this time the user wants to get out of the app because he thinks it is not loading and presses the home button before the "WhenActivated" of the first View is called.  Then he taps the app icon again. This will trigger the event chain that I've described in my question. I've manages to handle the events as they come, but I think that "WhenActivated"  should never come after "App.OnSleep"